# Laravel - using simple auth driver 'Uninitialized string offset: 0'

Tags: laravel

Hi I've been looking into Laravel framework but cannot get this auth driver to work! returns:

Unhandled Exception

```
Message:

Uninitialized string offset: 0
Location:

C:\wamp\www\site\laravel\auth\drivers\eloquent.php on line 39
```

I have a login controller with:

```
class Login_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $restful = true;

    public function post_index()
    {
        $username = Input::get('username');
        $password = Input::get('password');

        if ( Auth::attempt($username, $password) )
        {
            return Redirect::to('home');
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::to('login')->with('login_errors', true);
        }

    }

    public function get_index() {

        return View::make('page.login');

    }

}
```

I have `'username' => 'username',`

in the auth.php for the row name

Has anyone else come across  this?

regards

phil

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it, need to pass the credentials to the attempt method by array:

```
<?php

class Login_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $restful = true;

    public function post_index()
    {
        $username = Input::get('username');
        $password = Input::get('password');

        if ( Auth::attempt( array( 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password ) ) )
        {
            return Redirect::to('home');
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::to('login')->with('login_errors', true);
        }

    }

    public function get_index() {

        return View::make('page.login');

    }

}
```